# Getting passbok view total in grid using c#

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am using `Data Grid` to show passbook balance. I have done everything I'm unable to get the balance value in the respective column.

```
  private void dgview2_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int credit1, debit1;
        int balance = new int();

        if (int.TryParse(dgview2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["debit"].Value.ToString(),
            out debit1) && int.TryParse(dgview2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["credit"].Value.ToString(), 
            out credit1) && int.TryParse(dgview2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["balance"].Value.ToString(),
            out balance))
        {
              balance = balance + credit1 - debit1;
            dgview2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["balance"].Value = balance.ToString();
        }

    }
```

[Vfp9sp2 Application output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5orZ.jpg)

Comment: CellEndEdit event occurs when edit mode stops for the currently selected cell. Have you tried editing a cell in each row in the grid?

Comment: Thanks !, I have made the grid read only . So it is not possible . Actually this is a passbook display grid so cell values  can't be be edited or modified . Only the problem is balance column not showing proper result . I can't understand why ? .

Comment: Where do you source the data for your grid? Is it coming from database or you populating each cell manually?

Comment: my data source is mysql database . I am calling it and populating with the grid .

Answer (score 0):

The reason code does not work is that grid is made read only, therefore code specified in the event handler (`dgview2_CellEndEdit`) is not triggered.

Ideally you should be making balance calculations before updating the grid, but as a quick workaround you can move the code to a private method like this:

```
private void UpdateBalance()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgview2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        int credit1, debit1, balance;

        if (int.TryParse(dgview2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                out debit1) && int.TryParse(dgview2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                out credit1) && int.TryParse(dgview2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
                out balance))
        {
            balance = balance + credit1 - debit1;
            dgview2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = balance.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Then call this method after you finished populating the grid:

```
UpdateBalance();
```

The method iterates over each row and updates balance cells using the same logic.

**[Edit for update code]**

Instead of above, you can perform calculation in your update logic as below:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    var n = dgview2.Rows.Add();
    dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["tdate"].ToString());
    dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr["particular"].ToString();
    dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = dr["trmode"].ToString();
    dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = dr["debit"].ToString();
    dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = dr["credit"].ToString();
    dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = dr["balance"].ToString();     

    int credit1, debit1, balance;

    if (int.TryParse(dr["debit"].ToString(),
        out debit1) && int.TryParse(dr["credit"].ToString(),
        out credit1) && int.TryParse(dr["balance"].ToString(),
        out balance))
    {
        dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = balance + credit1 - debit1;
    }

    dgview2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = n;
    dgview2.CurrentCell = dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[0];
}
```

Comment: error " Column named debit cannot be found.\r\nParameter name: columnName"}"

Comment: here is the code which i am using to populate data grid

Comment: Updated an answer with indexes instead of row names

Answer (score 0):

here is the code which i am useing to populate grid

```
  private void fill_div()
    {
        var com = new MySqlCommand("Select *From shtrn where mem_no ='" + textBox1.Text + "' order by tdate  ", con_db.con);
        var dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            dgview2.Rows.Clear();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var n = dgview2.Rows.Add();
                dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["tdate"].ToString());
                dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr["particular"].ToString();
                dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = dr["trmode"].ToString();
                dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = dr["debit"].ToString();
                dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = dr["credit"].ToString();
                dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = dr["balance"].ToString();
                dgview2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = n;
                dgview2.CurrentCell = dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[0];
                UpdateBalance();
            }
            {

                dr.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Records Found ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: error  " Column named balance cannot be found.\r\nParameter name: columnName"} "

Comment: You are calling `UpdateBalance()` inside of the loop (multiple times). It should be called after the loop.

Comment: Hi , its not making any calculation i.e.     balance = balance + credit1 - debit1

Comment: What do you mean? Which code line is not making the calculation?

Comment: this  "  dgview2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = balance + credit1 - debit1; "  it is in populated data event .

Comment: What values are you getting for credit1, debit1, balance?

Comment: i am getting proper values of credit and debit column ( which are saved in database table )  . but the balance column is not getting proper values i.e.  balance = balance + credit - debit  ( it shows credit values or debit values in balance column for respective credit and debit .

Comment: yes the same code i am running . tell me one thing should i change the column name in grid view design time ? i have name i.e.  like column1,column2, ........at design time .

Comment: Sure, it won't do any harm

Comment: Please see the Required grid output in Jpg attached with main question . Actully I am New In C # but I am developing in Vfp9Sp2 . This Jpg is output of Vfp9 Application .